# Update local master to remote master from another branch

Tags: git

I have a **devel**  branch and **origin/master** has been updated.  I run `git pull` and I can see the remote changes.  However, my local **master** is still where I left it when I previously did `git checkout devel`.  I want to merge the **origin/master** changes to my **devel** branch; such a branch also exists on the remote.

I would prefer not to checkout the **master** branch as I will end up rebuilding a massive system.  Can I move my local **master** to the **origin/master** from a different branch?  Then I can do a `merge` from **devel**.  Or is it easier just to `merge` the **origin/master** to **devel** directly?  That seems like it will be trouble later on?

Edit: Another way to avoid this problem is to use different work spaces with the same repository.
See: [git new workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/) -  You may have both **master** and **devel** checked out at the same time but using the same *.git* repository.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only difference between updating your local `master` to `origin/master` and then merging it, vs. just merging `origin/master` directly, is the pre-generated commit message on the merge (well, assuming you eventually update `master`). So I say just merge in `origin/master`.

---

That said, to answer the question "how do I update a local non-checked-out branch to match its tracking branch", you can say

```
git push . origin/master:master
```

This uses the `git push` machinery, but a repository of `.` means "the current repo". Your source branch is specified as `origin/master` and your remote branch as `master`, so this updates `master` to match `origin/master`. You could do the same thing with the plumbing command `git update-ref`, but using `git push` is simpler and a bit safer (because it will prevent non-fast-forward merges by default, and I believe it will also prevent pushing to your checked-out branch).

Comment: Hey that’s a cool trick with the local push, nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, `git pull` will fetch from the remote branch and merge into your current branch. If you don’t specify a branch in the `git pull` command, Git will use the one specified for your branch, usually the remote tracking branch.

So running `git pull` in your *devel* branch would fetch the *devel* branch from the remote and merge changes from there, but not from master.

Note that just running `git fetch` will update all remote branches for the remote. So `origin/master` will be updated after fetching, allowing you to merge that one into your current branch using just `git merge origin/master`.

Obviously this will not update your local *master* though, so you might want to update that later too, before merging your *devel* branch into it.